# How to avoid cutting corners with A* pathfinding?

Tags: c#, path-finding

On my second try with A* I managed to calculate all values needed for traceback. Also marked the starting cell with S, blocked with B and the goal cell with F.

[image]

Now for the backtracking I would simply follow the cells with lowest G value, starting from goal cell.

Here I would follow G=24 => G=10 => S.

As you can see this solution would create a path which is not valid because it leads throught a wall in this case.

This hangs together with corner cutting when calculating the values for a grid. As you can see here. One would backtrace: G=50 => G= 40 and here one would take G=20 next. This leads to the corner cutting.

[image]

I think this issue occurs when calculating the values for each adjacent cell. Maybe I could avoid this if I set some restrictions when adding adjacent cells to the current cell?

```
public List<Cell> GetAdjacent(Cell _currentCell, List<Cell> _closedList, List<Cell> _gridList) 
    {
        List<Cell> adjacentList = new List<Cell>();
        List<Cell> gridList = _gridList;
        List<Cell> closedList = _closedList;
        Cell currentCell = _currentCell;

        foreach (Cell cell in gridList) 
        {
            bool containedInClosedList = closedList.Any(c => c.id == cell.id);

            if (!cell.blocked && !containedInClosedList && 
                ((cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X - 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X + 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y - 1) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y + 1) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X - 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y - 1) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X - 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y + 1) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X + 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y - 1) ||
                (cell.positionCR.X == currentCell.positionCR.X + 1 && cell.positionCR.Y == currentCell.positionCR.Y + 1)))
            {
                adjacentList.Add(cell);
            }

        }



        return adjacentList;
    }
```

Could it also be a problem with the custom costs I defined? I took a G=10 for straight and G=14 for diagonal cells.

I think this is the last thing which stops me from finishing the algorithm, so I am looking forward for any help or constructive input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have described an adequate solution to your "corner cutting" problem -- if a path would cut through such a corner, you simply never add the path to the collection of candidate paths. So I'm not sure what you're asking in this question.

Comment: How do I check if it cuts a corner?

Comment: Your cost metric of 10 for straight movement and 14 for diagonal movement is reasonable but has one small potential problem. The `A*` algorithm requires for its correctness that the approximation metric *underestimates* the distance to the goal. If you are using the Euclidean metric as your approximation then you might be *overestimating* by the difference between 14 and 10 times root 2, which is about 1%. Such a tiny overestimation is unlikely to produce really bad results, but it's worth at least thinking about whether there's a better weighting that keeps the metric admissible.

Comment: Well you tell me: what are all the cases where a step in a path cuts a corner? There are only four of them, so you should be able to enumerate them easily.

Comment: So this could be a weightening issue?

Comment: Your corner cutting problem is not a weighting issue. It's the fact that you're allowing the step at all. You have a method that determines adjacent nodes; if an adjacent node would cut a corner, don't add it to the list.

Comment: I note also that your method seems potentially very inefficient. There are only eight possible neighbours, but every time you call this method you check every cell to see if it is one of those eight. What if there are a million cells? Do you really want to ask all million of them if they are among those eight?

Comment: If you're having difficulty understanding this algorithm you might want to read my series of articles on it -- but that said, I encourage you to try to work this out on your own rather than just copying my code. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/astar/

Comment: Thank You! Any advice on how to get the adjacent cells more efficient?

Comment: Produce a list with the eight possible neighbours and then check each of them to see if they are valid -- on the board, not cutting corners, etc.  That way you're filtering eight things, not a million things.

Comment: @EricLippert so this is a while ago. Would you mind to sum up your suggestions in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Eric mentioned in the comments above, you could produce a list with with the eight possible neighbours and check if they are valid. Valid here does not only mean to check if they are blocked, you also should check for corner cutting here.